# Looping through Json array on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

What I have is an array that has several values

```
Array
(
    [result] => 1
    [message] => Query Successful
    [data] => Query Output
    [0] => Array
    (
        [QNO] => 1
        [SNAME] => test1
        [QDESC] => testing
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [QNO] => 2
        [SNAME] => test2
        [QDESC] =>  testing

    )
```

and so on with more data. I want to be able to extract that in my php script. The data shown was from printing the decoded array with

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

I can print everything with `print_r()` but I want to be able to print using a loop so I can create a table with it.

To try an output of all the question numbers I tried a rough for loop using

```
for($i = 0; $i <=5; i++){
 $Qnum = $data[$i]['QNO'];
 echo $Qnum[$i];
 $i++;

}
```

but this seems to just keep loading and loading the script with no output. The `print_r($data)` prints everything out as shown above.

Still fairly new to php/json stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error.

You need to add the $ before i++, and remove the $i++ inside the loop (or you'll increment $i twice). You don't see anything on screen because probably the server is configured not to display any error.
At the  beginning of the script add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

```
for($i = 0; $i <=5; $i++){
 $Qnum = $data[$i]['QNO'];
 echo $Qnum;

}
```

Comment: The `echo $Qnum[$i];` should also be `echo $Qnum;`.